# Is the order important when we toss two coins?

Tags: probability

It always seems confusing to tell whether the order of objects in probability questions is important or not. Suppose that we have two fair identical coins. We conduct two experiments.

1. We toss the first coin first and then we toss the second coin. Since we can distinguish between $(H,T)$ and $(T,H)$ ($H$ denotes heads and $T$ denotes tails), the sample space is given by
   $$
   \Omega_1=\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)\}
   $$
   and all outcomes are equally probable.
2. We toss both of the coins at the same time. Hence, we cannot distinguish between $(H,T)$ and $(T,H)$ and the sample space is given by
   $$
   \Omega_2=\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,T)\}.
   $$
   But now the outcomes are not equally probable, are they?

So it seems that the order is intrinsically important in both of these experiments and even in the case when we toss both of the coins at the same time we should still think that we can distinguish between $(H,T)$ and $(T,H)$. Does $\Pr\{(H,T)\}=1/3$ ever make sense?

If the order is important, then all the outcomes are equally probable, but if the order is not important, then the outcomes should not be treated as equally probable. Does that make sense?

Are there any good examples that clear up this confusion?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: That's right. It is not really about simultaneity, but about the choice of sample space. The three-element sample space does not consist of equiprobable outcomes, and is therefore somewhat inconvenient for computation of probabilities.  As to $1/3$ ever making sense perhaps look at Bose-Einstein statistics.

Comment: The order is not what you need to focus on here. You are actually describing the same event space in two different ways: one in which probabilities are uniform and one in which the probabilities are not uniformly distributed.

Comment: A similar issue comes up with rolling dice-- if the dice are identical there are not really 36 observably distinguishable outcomes (21 actually) but we (almost) always model dice rolls as 36 equally likely outcomes rather than 21 with each of the doubles half as likely as the others. But the 21 outcome model would work fine, just not as convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coins are still unique individual entities, and the probabilities of atomic outcomes of the coin toss do not change; even if the distinction between some of them is hidden from an observer.

Thus the event of: "I see a head and a tail", is still either: "the oldest coin is head and the other tail", or "the oldest coin is tail and the other head", even if you don't know which coin is older than the other.   So $$\mathsf P\Big(\overbrace{\{(C_1,C_2),(C_2,C_1)\}}^\textrm{can't tell the order of the coins}\ni({\sf H, T})\Big)\;=\;\mathsf P\Big((C_1,C_2)\in\overbrace{\{{\sf (H,T),(T,H)}\}}^\textrm{don't care about order of result}\Big) \\ =2/4$$

So no, you cannot simply count distinctly observable outcomes to measure the probability.   You need a model which determines the probability weight of each observable result.